# analog input for virtual oscilloscope

Tags: linux, ubuntu, signals, qemu, oscilloscope

fellows
   I am designing a virtual oscilloscope with Qt or EFL for running in Qemu (for mini2440) in OS Ubuntu.
   There should be 4 analog inputs / signal, and then do the sampling with determined frequency, and then do some other calculation.
   Is there anyone can give me some clews or inspirations about how to generate the analog input / signal for the oscilloscope to deal with?
   Thank you very much!

Sincerely.

Oscar

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the analog signal into data for your program?

Comment: still unsolved? cant help with your platform but if you need algorithms for rendering just ask ... btw look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21658139/2521214

Answer (score 1):

A typical [Analog-to-Digital Conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) solution for home-brewn oscilloscopes is to use the inputs of your sound card. Depending on your requirements, you could even add an extra card or two to make more inputs available.

Most sound-cards will sample at 44.1, 48 or 96 kHz, so that kind of sampling rate is only suitable for audio applications. On the other hand, you have at least two channels for free in most computers - and if you need more you can always use a `usbaudio` device.

You might want to have a look at [xoscope](http://xoscope.sourceforge.net) which uses this approach.

If you need to go higher than that sampling rate then you are looking for lab-grade [Data Acquisition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_acquisition) devices. There are some relatively cheap solutions, but the key word here is *relatively* - they are generally quite pricey, at least for personal use.