# plotting real time Data on (qwt )Oscillocope

Tags: c++, plot, qwt, real-time-data

I'm trying to create a program, using Qt (c++), which can record audio from my microphone using QAudioinput and QIODevice. 
Now, I want to visualize my signal

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**[Edit1]** - copied from your comment (by Spektre)

- I Have only one Buffer for both channel
- I use Qt , the value of channel are interlaced on buffer
- this is how I separate values

  ```
  for ( int i = 0, j = 0; i < countSamples ; ++j) 
   {
   YVectorRight[j]=Samples[i++];
   YVectorLeft[j] =Samples[i++];
   }
  ```
- after I plot YvectorRight and YvectorLeft. I don't see how to trigger only one channel

Comment: +1 for uncommon HW related question. look at my answer. edit your question a little add what you have tried already and what you need to solve. any edit flag with visible text (i do it [edit1],[edit2]) and also add comment that you have editet something so anyone in comment list obtain a notice

Comment: I am not using QT/QWT but you can use timer or thread function (timer is an component add it to window set interval and in it ontimer event do the drawing) for thread just use CreateThread ... (in Windows and in linux is i think the same)

Answer (score 1):

hehe done this few years back for students during class. I hope you know how oscilloscopes works so here are just the basics:

1. **timebase**

   - `fsmpl` is input signal sampling frequency [Hz]

   Try to use as big as possible `(44100,48000, ???)` so the max frequency detected is then `fsmpl/2` this gives you the top of your timebase axis. The low limit is given by your buffer length
2. **draw**

   Create function that will render your sampling buffer from specified start address (inside buffer) with:

   - Y-scale ... amplitude setting
   - Y-offset ... Vertical beam position
   - X-offset ... Time shift or horizontal position

   This can be done by modification of start address or by just X-offsetting the curve
3. **Level**

   Create function which will emulate **Level** functionality. So search buffer from start address and stop if amplitude cross Level. You can have more modes but these are basics you should implement:

   - amplitude: `( < lvl ) -> ( > lvl )`
   - amplitude: `( > lvl ) -> ( < lvl )`

   There are many other possibilities for level like glitch,relative edge,...
4. **Preview**

   You can put all this together for example like this: you have `start address` variable so sample data to some buffer continuously and on timer call `level` with `start address` (and update it). Then call draw with new `start address` and add `timebase period` to `start address` (of course in term of your samples)
5. **multichannel**

   I use **Line** IN so I have stereo input (A,B = left,right) therefore I can add some other stuff like:

   - Level source (`A,B`,none)
   - render mode (timebase,Chebyshev (Lissajous curve if closed))
   - Chebyshev = `x` axis is `A`, `y` axis is `B` this creates famous Chebyshev images which are good for dependent sinusoidal signals. Usually forming circles,ellipses,distorted loops ...
6. **miscel stuff**

   You can add filters for channels emulating capacitance or grounding of input and much more
7. **GUI**

   You need many settings I prefer analog knobs instead of buttons/scrollbars/sliders just like on real Oscilloscope

   - (semi)Analog values: Amplitude,TimeBase,Level,X-offset,Y-offset
   - discrete values: level mode(/,),level source(A,B,-),each channel (direct on,ground,off,capacity on)

Here are some screenshots of my oscilloscope:

[image: oscilloscope]
[image: oscilloscope]

Here is screenshot of my generator:

[image: generator]

And finally after adding some FFT also Spectrum Analyser

[image: Spectrum analyser]

**PS.**

- I started with **DirectSound** but it sucks a lot because of buggy/non-functional buffer callbacks
- I use **WinAPI WaveIn/Out** for all sound in my Apps now. After few quirks with it, is the best for my needs and has the best latency (Directsound is too slow more than 10 times) but for oscilloscope it has no merit (I need low latency mostly for emulators)

Btw. I have these three apps as linkable C++ subwindow classes (Borland)

- and last used with my ATMega168 emulator for my sensor-less BLDC driver debugging
- here you can try my [Oscilloscope,generator and Spectrum analyser](http://ulozto.net/xFASrEPv/soundio-exe-rar) If you are confused with download read the comments below this post **btw password is: "oscill"**

Hope it helps if you need help with anything just comment me

**[Edit1] trigger**

You trigger all channels at once but the trigger condition is checked usually just from one Now the implementation is simple for example let the **trigger condition** be the **A(left) channel rise above level** so:

1. first make continuous playback with no trigger you wrote it is like this:

   ```
   for ( int i = 0, j = 0; i < countSamples ; ++j) 
    {
    YVectorRight[j]=Samples[i++];
    YVectorLeft[j] =Samples[i++];
    }
   // here draw or FFT,draw  buffers YVectorRight,YVectorLeft
   ```
2. Add trigger

   To add trigger condition you just find sample that meets it and start drawing from it so you change it to something like this

   ```
   // static or global variables
   static int i0=0; // actual start for drawing
   static bool _copy_data=true; // flag that new samples need to be copied
   static int level=35; // trigger level value datatype should be the same as your samples...

   int i,j;
   for (;;)
    {
    // copy new samples to buffer if needed
    if (_copy_data)
     for (_copy_data=false,i=0,j=0;i<countSamples;++j) 
     {
     YVectorRight[j]=Samples[i++];
     YVectorLeft[j] =Samples[i++];
     }
    // now search for new start
    for (i=i0+1;i<countSamples>>1;i++) 
     if (YVectorLeft[i-1]<level) // lower then level before i
      if (YVectorLeft[i]>=level) // higher then level after i
       {
       i0=i;
       break;
       }
    if (i0>=(countSamples>>1)-view_samples) { i0=0; _copy_data=true; continue; }
    break;
    }
   // here draw or FFT,draw  buffers YVectorRight,YVectorLeft from i0 position
   ```

   - the `view_samples` is the viewed/processed size of data (for one or more screens) it should be few times less then the `(countSamples>>1)`
   - this code can loose one screen on the border area to avoid that you need to implement cyclic buffers (rings) but for starters is even this OK
   - just encode all trigger conditions through some if's or switch statement

Comment: you can post your code in your question so others can also see and help(just don't forget to select it and click on the code format button so it will be viewed in that gray area with syntax highlights and code line formating) if you add code under bullet add n*4 spaces in each line until it is gray. For sub questions add them to your question also (number them for example Q1,Q2,...) and we will try to answer them (i am sure someone else will add to this). btw i code mostly in bds2006 C++ win32 so questions related to Qwt or different platform will have to answer someone else anyway.

Comment: PS. download this: http://ulozto.sk/xFASrEPv/soundio-exe-rar password is "oscill" it uses preferred sound input and output from windows sound settings

Comment: hello Spektre, how do you generate a triangular and square waveform ?

Comment: @user2932518 easy with for loop or precomputed table  ... with for loop triangular shape is for (i=0;i<N;i++) for first half out[i] = Amplitude*i/(N/2-1) and for second out[i] = Amplitude*(N-i-1)/(N/2-1); the square wave is also relatively easy ... if (i>ratio) out[i] = 0 else out[i] = Amplitude;

Comment: I Have only one Buffer  for  both channel, I use Qt , the  value  of  channel are interlaced on buffer. this ist how I separate value for ( int i = 0, j = 0; i < countSamples ; ++j) {
      YVectorRight[j] =Samples[i++];            
             
      YVectorLeft[j] = Samples[i++];
 } after I plot YvectorRight and YvectorLeft. I don't see how to trigger only one channel

Comment: @TheMan have edited answer look for Edit1. btw your comments jumps from question to question if I haven't seen them both I would not know to what you are referring to. Yes it is more suited here then to your spectrum analyser question but the original comment is there :) be careful with this in the future because other users will have no clue what is you writing about an therefore they cannot help. Also try add more info to your questions not just what you want but also what you have done so far + some code example so others can actually help (that is why your trigger question get closed).