# simple user creatable 2-d graphical interface

Tags: user-interface, c++builder, graphics2d

I can create some nice number crunching programs for power system analysis.  But what I lack is a nice graphical interface that a user can create, modify, and save (instead of just typing data into input files).

Are there any packages/libraries available that would give my programs a front-end to allow the user to interface via graphical 2-d interface?

For example, below is a simple drawing depicting part of a power system.  The objects that i've annotated are the ones i want users to be able to add, delete, double-click on to edit numerical properties etc.   I would also like for the connecting lines to resize if the user moves one of the objects around.  The idea is to have a nice interface that actually represents the power system (instead of users typing data into text input files).

[image]
I don't need anything more complicated than that - but i really don't know where to start.  If there are packages that can accomplish this now i'd much prefer to buy them for my front-end instead of spending months of my life learning how to create some sludgy interface.

I would appreciate any sound direction.  I use C and C++ for my code but the interface could be anything i suppose.  Once the user had the drawing like he/she liked it they would simply hit "GO" and the text input files would be automatically created from the data they input via the drawing.

The user would simply create the drawing, double-click each element to edit the data fields for that object, and then click "GO".

Comment: take a look at [Does anyone know of a low level (no frameworks) example of a drag & drop, re-order-able list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20924609/2521214) you can use/adapt/modiffy it to suite your needs. It is written in BDS2006 (successor of BCB6) so it should working in any BCB version ... Here another form of custom GUI [How to implement a constraint solver for 2-D geometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40827518/2521214) and lastly see [Simple OpenGL GUI Framework User Interaction Advice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34250889/2521214) for some ideas

Comment: Thanks Spektre, but that is so far beyond my ability I'd have to become a real programmer to use.  Are there any tools (like Visio etc.) that can be used as front-ends, just to let user make drawings, input data and hand off to other programs?

Comment: ATPDraw is an example of what I want - it lets users draw diagrams, move pieces around, double-click to edit data.  THEN it spits out the data to a completely independent program that runs the analysis.  ATPDraw is just a convenient user interface.  https://www.atpdraw.net/

Comment: Have a look at this component: https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/diagram.asp