# How do you render an audio data like this?

Tags: audio, graphics, pcm, oscilloscope

How would you render an audio wave form like [this](https://youtu.be/nNsUcqL5JCg?t=35s) from PCM data?

Comment: audio is just a wave ... the raw audio format is PCM ... every wave has an X and Y component ... X records time and Y audio amplitude ... the video displays this curve ... it has direct physical analogs of how your ear drum wobbles in response to the wobble of your friends vocal cords

Comment: yep simple oscillogram without any funny stuff you just need trigger level function to find the best start so the waves will not shift (like in oscilloscope) see [plotting real time Data on (qwt )Oscillocope](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21658139/2521214)